# Spring WebFlux - Flux Buffer / Memory Consumption

Tags: spring-data, spring-webflux, spring-data-mongodb, flux

I've created an API in my controller to return Flux:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/orderStreams", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<OrderResponseDTO> getAllOrders() {
   return orderService.getAll()
    .map(order -> modelMapper.map(order, OrderResponseDTO.class));
}
```

Now there can be up to 100k order documents that this orderService can return as server set events.

My question is whether Flux takes up heap memory to hold all 100k documents in this process?